# How to Make Lines Automatically Adjust same with Another Line (Route or Road)

Tags: qgis, line, route, polyline-creation

I have 1000 lines and 1 route or road line. I want to automatically my lines adjust to route or road without erasing all data in the attribute table. My expected results, 900 lines will same with the route. I used QGIS 2.18

This is my lines

[image]

and this is the route/road line
[image]

Comment: Can you upgrade to QGIS 3.0? `Snap geometries to layer` tool does exactly what you want to.

Comment: I will try to upgrade my QGIS. @Kazuhito Is it (`Snap geometries to layer`) plugin?

Comment: You can find it in `Processing Toolbox` | (QGIS) `Vector geometry`

Comment: I upgrade my QGIS and use `Snap geometries to layer`, but I get error result. Error Message _Message  _Feature (508) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option. Execution failed after 0.86 seconds_

Comment: Oh. Have you been successful in removing geometry errors?

Comment: @Kazuhito, No, I haven’t yet. I don’t know how to do it, because I try mant ways in this tool but still get some errors.

Comment: How to remove geometry errors? because I have to much line to edit manual

Comment: Geometry error is always hard to fix. There are various tools, but my suggestion is `Geometry checker`. It is one of core plugin but you need to activate from Plugin manager. Then you can find in `Vector | Geometry Tools | Check geometries`. Be careful, there is another `Vector | Geometry Tools` sub-menu which includes Check validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you can fix the geometry error soon. After that, please try **Snap geometries to layer** which is available in QGIS 3.0.

A small test:

Input: Line 1 (green) and Line 2 (red)

[image]

Output: Snapped Line 1 (green dots) and Line 2 (red dots)

[image]

There are some corners left unsnapped. If you see such incomplete lines, please repeat using this tool again. I mean, snap using the snapped line.

Final output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for complete answer, but first I have to clean all errors,,, thank you

Comment: @Arief yes, cleaning dataset is the most time consuming part... Good luck.