# QGIS autoadjust the line to another existing line nearby

Tags: qgis, line, linestring

I have the line created by the "Point to path" function. The algorithm produces just a straight line, whereas I would like to have this line auto-adjusted to the other line (or buffer) which actually exists.

[image]

I found the solution here:

[How to Make Lines Automatically Adjust same with Another Line (Route or Road)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283823/how-to-make-lines-automatically-adjust-same-with-another-line-route-or-road)

but it's based on the Snapping tool, which still requires some manual work even if I enable tracing.

I am wondering about some option, which would adjust the line automatically to the selected line from another layer.

Comment: You linked answer is not based on the manual snapping tool, but the [processing one](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnapgeometries)

Comment: Rather than using 'point to path', can you use the 'shortest path (point to point)' tool from network analysis?

Comment: @firefly-orange you are great! This is exactly the one! Do you know how to deal with more than 1 at once?

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [shortest path (point to point)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html?highlight=shortest%20path#shortest-path-point-to-point) tool for this purpose. To run it for multiple instances you can use the [batch processing interface](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html?highlight=batch)